# How to apply an equality filter to a Users request?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I'm trying to make a call to the MS Graph Users API using C# and the `GraphServiceClient`. I'm trying to filter by `Mail` but no matter what format I try, it gets rejected due to an invalid query. I've tried all the examples I've found on the interwebs but I can't seem to find one that uses the service client to filter users by equality.

I've tried the following in `Filter`.

`$"eq('Mail', '{email}')"`,
`$"equal('Mail', '{email}')"`,
`$"equals('Mail', '{email}')"`,
and `$"'Mail' eq '{email}'"`

```
await _graphClient
    .Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();
```

I did [find a way to filter users](https://iqunlock.com/microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp/#microsoft-graph-explorer) where my tenant is the issuer but I need to be able to also search for invited users as well.

`var filter = $"Identities/any(id:id/Issuer eq '{TenantName}' and id/IssuerAssignedId eq '{emailAddress}')";`

Removing the equality check on the `TenantName` makes it an invalid filter.

**What am I doing wrong here; is it possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the filter in my code for your reference:

```
var response = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("mail eq 'test@mail.com'").GetAsync();
```

Comment: Okay! Camel-case prop-names without quotes - excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is to pass the email directly in URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@mail.com
```

Code:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["test@mail.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: I tried that and it couldn't find external users by actual email: "Resource 'some@example.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present." That's without any filtering applied. However, giving it the principal name worked though that's less than ideal due to having to manipulate external emails into the ugly principal name value. `some_example#EXT#@my.domain.com`, for example.